# Lazy load Oauth2Decorator callback_handler using webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, webapp2

This works fine :

```
secrets = 'client_secrets-gae.json'
decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), secrets),
                                          scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
....

webapp2.Route('/oauth2callback', handler=decorator.callback_handler() ),
```

But how can I lazy load the callback [using webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#custom-methods). I have to refer to the decorator instance :

```
webapp2.Route(r'/products', handler='handlers.ProductsHandler', name='products-list', handler_method='list_products')
```

**Update and solved**

This line `decorator.callback_handler()` creates a request handler object.

```
decorator_callback_handler =  decorator.callback_handler()

.... 

webapp2.Route('/oauth2callback', handler='my_package.my_mod.decorator_callback_handler'),
```

And ofcourse I use different modules for handling the decorator and the webapp2 routes to benefit from the lazy load.

Answer (score 1):

This line `decorator.callback_handler()` returns a webapp.RequestHandler that handles the redirect back from the server during the OAuth 2.0 dance.

From : callback_handler docstring in oath2client.appengine

So the solution is :

use_api.py :

```
secrets = 'client_secrets-gae.json'
decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), secrets),
                                      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')

decorator_callback_handler =  decorator.callback_handler()
```

And lazy load this handler in main.py :

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([        
        ....                            # other routes                                             
        webapp2.Route('/oauth2callback', handler='package.use_api.decorator_callback_handler'),                      
    ], debug=True)
```